# Waiting for a timer to terminate before continuing running the code

Tags: python, pyside

The following code updates the text of a button every second after the `START` button was pressed. The intended functionality is for the code to 'wait' until the timer has stopped before continuing on with the execution of the code. That is, after `START` is pressed, the text of the second button is incremented to `3`, and only then should the text `I waited!` appear on the console.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)

        self.app_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.app_layout)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 50, 50)

        self.current_count = 0

        self.count_to = 4
        self.delay = 1000

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateButtonCount) 

        # start button
        start_button = QtGui.QPushButton()
        start_button.setText('START')
        start_button.clicked.connect(self.startCount)
        self.app_layout.addWidget(start_button)

        # number button
        self.number_button = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.number_button.setText('0')
        self.app_layout.addWidget(self.number_button)



    def updateButtonCount(self):
        self.number_button.setText("%s" % self.current_count)
        self.current_count += 1
        if self.current_count == self.count_to:
            self.timer.stop()


    def startCount(self):
        self.current_count = 0
        self.timer.start(self.delay)

        # this loop hangs the GUI:
        while True:
            if not self.timer.isActive():
                break

        print 'I waited!'


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    example = Example()
    example.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The above code hangs the GUI, and if I remove the `while True:` loop, the `I waited!` appears immidiately on the console.

I'm certain that the `while True:` loop is not the correct way to go about it, so I'm looking for suggestions.

Comment: Instead of using while True, make the while to be running until self.timer.isActive(). `while self.timer.isActive(): pass` The code will do the same, but I don't like the infinite loops

Comment: Yes, that's definitely better style. But it doesn't solve my problem :(

Comment: Have you seen this post [HowTo use QTIMER inside Qthread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025644/how-to-use-qtimer-inside-qthread-which-uses-qwaitcondition-pyside)? Not sure if you're looking for some like this, but maybe can help you to get some idea

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found that works was to replace

```
while True:
    if not self.timer.isActive():
        break
```

with

```
while self.timer.isActive():
    QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
```

I'm not certain that this is the best solution, though.